# Xcode 6.2 iOS target 6.1: self.view endEditing:YES throws exception unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `textField` that pulls up a decimal pad keyboard.
I added a tap gesture recognizer in my `.xib` and I want to close the keyboard when anyone taps on the screen.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *billTextField;
- (IBAction)onTap:(id)sender;
@end
@implementation TipViewController
- (IBAction)onTap:(id)sender {
    self.title = @"Tap detected";
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
@end
```

This throws the following exception:

```
[TipViewController billTextField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd6dac50630
2015-03-28 22:19:59.747 TipCalculator[32959:3666939] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TipViewController billTextField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd6dac50630'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The error is that there is no function named billTextField. And the controller is looking for that and throwing error. Check your xib file's owner. May be u have added an action but not defined.

Comment: Somewhere you are accidentally using billTextField like a method instead of a property.  It's not in the code that you posted.  Do you have exception breakpoints set?

Comment: spot on. Thanks Jassi and Bek. xib file owner had a action defined on billTextField. Getting rid of it took care of the issue. Thanks!